# 09 Yamaha 250 V-Star bogs down when throttle is twisted

Tags: motorcycle, starting, yamaha, vstar

I just finally got my first bike it's a 2009 Yamaha 250 V-Star.

I bought a new carburetor and I have got it running, but when I seem to give it a lot of throttle it starts backfiring and bogs down.

I just don't know what to do  can someone please help?

Comment: A new carb, have you set the idle and mixture etc?

Answer (score 0):

Backfiring is usually a sign of the engine running rich - unburnt fuel is passing into the exhaust system.

Assuming it's a new carb for that exact model bike, I would assume it needs to be synchronized.

This can be done with vacuum balancing kits [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GZHYRMQ). (Link to Amazon)

If this doesn't resolve your issue, check your air filter.  If it's plugged up and not letting enough air through, this will also lead to a rich condition.